# I deleted webapi url record from dns zone but still able to access

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-dns

I have deleted web-api url record from azure dns zone but still able to access.
How much time it will take to refresh?
Can I do it manually?

I tried with incognito browser mode but still I am able to access.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, Maximum it should take only 60 seconds to take the [`changes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-faq#how-long-does-it-take-for-dns-changes-to-take-effect).

Try clearing the cache or in different browser

Comment: Adding to Sajeetharan's suggestion, On a Windows machine, you could clear the cache with ipconfig /flushdns.
If the issue persists, Are you referring to App Service URL?